# iCloud lists 3.5GB data used due to Backups, but these are not listed and so can't be deleted

Tags: icloud, backup

Recently I've been getting errors that my iCloud storage is full. I tried deleting backups and data to clear it out. Now, if I go to 'iCloud Storage', I see this, i.e. 3.5GB of my iCloud being taken up by backups.

[image]

However, when I click on backups, I see this. No backups are listed and according to this page 0 memory is being taken up by backups.

[image]

I've gone on all my devices and iCloud for Windows to delete backups and I see the same thing everywhere. Can't figure out a way to delete the phantom backup or completely erase my iCloud data which I'd be willing to do.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try the web client avail. at [iCloud.com](https://icloud.com), in settings, you should have the option to erase specific data.

Comment: @bret7600 Checked settings but I can't see where to delete specific data? It shows me a breakdown of my storage but there are no management options.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; iCloud storage showed 4.2GB of backups data, but no backups. I tried deleting the 0KB backup too, which seems to do something, but doesn't resolve the issue.

I contacted [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/): started with the chat option, sent screenshots, was escalated to the phone support, because the chat agents don't have enough access I guess. Then was escalated again to a senior support agent. All of them could see no backups in my iCloud account, but I could (and they confirmed) that my iCloud storage was indeed including a backup neither me nor them could find.

There is a button that the senior support agent found that can clean up the used (but unused) storage of an iCloud account. Apparently, the chat support should have access to it, but maybe they don't know about it, and they didn't see it. The senior support agent found the button, tried it, and magic, the ghost backup was gone from my iCloud storage, and I was able to do a regular backup again.

Comment: Apple support has a very good process to escalate these issues and you may need to generate a support PIN to share with them so they can access your files if needed. Apple designs in several layers of privacy preserving features where support staff can only see summary information and not as much as we, the people that made the iCloud accounts can see.